# Change 'Log in', 'Log out', 'My account' menu text

Tags: 8

Is there a way that the default text in the account menu can be changed within the theme?

Comment: I think this might be better to close as a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263774/how-to-change-title-of-log-in-link-in-account-menu-for-anonymous-users which has better answers even though it was posted more recently than this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a menu normally you'd change the text in edit menu section but since the text is defined by the user module you'd have to do a work around. The template that's printing it is links.html.twig. Which looks like:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a set of links.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: Attributes for the UL containing the list of links.
 * - links: Links to be output.
 *   Each link will have the following elements:
 *   - title: The link text.
 *   - href: The link URL. If omitted, the 'title' is shown as a plain text
 *     item in the links list. If 'href' is supplied, the entire link is passed
 *     to l() as its $options parameter.
 *   - attributes: (optional) HTML attributes for the anchor, or for the <span>
 *     tag if no 'href' is supplied.
 * - heading: (optional) A heading to precede the links.
 *   - text: The heading text.
 *   - level: The heading level (e.g. 'h2', 'h3').
 *   - attributes: (optional) A keyed list of attributes for the heading.
 *   If the heading is a string, it will be used as the text of the heading and
 *   the level will default to 'h2'.
 *
 *   Headings should be used on navigation menus and any list of links that
 *   consistently appears on multiple pages. To make the heading invisible use
 *   the 'visually-hidden' CSS class. Do not use 'display:none', which
 *   removes it from screen readers and assistive technology. Headings allow
 *   screen reader and keyboard only users to navigate to or skip the links.
 *   See http://juicystudio.com/article/screen-readers-display-none.php and
 *   http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H42.html for more information.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_links()
 */
#}
{% if links -%}
  {%- if heading -%}
    {%- if heading.level -%}
      <{{ heading.level }}{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</{{ heading.level }}>
    {%- else -%}
      <h2{{ heading.attributes }}>{{ heading.text }}</h2>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <ul{{ attributes }}>
    {%- for item in links -%}
      <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif %}
```

One way I think you could accomplish this is make a custom links template that refers to the account menu. You'd need to call it links--toolbar-user.html.twig. Then you could insert some logic like

```
{% if item.text == 'Log in' %}
New login text
{% endif %}
```

There may be other locations besides links.html.twig that bring up the account menu that would have to have custom templates as well, but that's the overall idea.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same but for a lot of items so working with the *menu--account.html.twig* was more confortable for me.

You can pick up string variable by using getUntranslatedString() method :

```
{% if item.title.getUntranslatedString() == 'Log in' %}
  <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
  {{ link("new login text", item.url) }}
```

And if you want to do it for multiple strings :

```
{% if item.title.getUntranslatedString() == 'Log in' %}
 <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
 {{ link('New login text', item.url) }}
{% elseif item.title.getUntranslatedString() == 'My account' %}
 <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
 {{ link('new my account' text, item.url) }}
{% elseif item.title.getUntranslatedString() == 'Log out' %}
 <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
 {{ link('new log out' text, item.url) }}
{% else %} {# when there is no match with the previous conditions #}
  <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
  {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
{% endif %}
```

Be sure to put your conditions before the trailing `</li>`